# ASP.NET Core Controllers Fail to Register with Authorization Package

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-authorization

My asp.net core 3.1 project throws an exception if I include this package (context: I’m trying to create a custom Authorization policy):

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="5.0.3" />
```

This is the exception and method where it is thrown in startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddControllers();
    System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'configure')'
```

This is the complete list of packages. Is there some conflict that I'm not aware of? The package was suggested by VS when I created an `AuthorizationHandler` class.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets" Version="1.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="CorrelationId" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.15.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="3.1.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="5.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.9" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="7.5.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="NSwag.AspNetCore" Version="13.8.2" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oops, looks like the answer was already available with a little more effort on my part. I resolved this by manually downgrading the package version to `3.1.12` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/222841/error-while-downgrading-project-from-net-5-to-net.html). Looks like VS gave me the .net version of the package instead of the .net core version.

Comment: Thank you very much. I downgraded Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization from 5.0.8 to 3.1.17 and it worked. You saved me a tons of time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was using an authorization handler form a .NET Standard 2 library where v.6.0.x was installed. Downgrading was not an option for me.

Exchanging `services.AddControllers()` with `services.AddMvcCore()` in my Core 3.1 project solved the problem for me.